# Pass a dynamic type

Tags: c#, reflection

I am aware of passing dynamic types with reflection but with the following class structure am having a little difficulty; where my calling class would be instantiating another class and calling a method on it's base class passing the method a dynamic type.

```
public class MainClass
{
    // var genericClass = new GenericClass();
    // genericClass.SomeMethod<T>();
    var myDynamicType = Type.GetType(FullyQualifiedNamespace + className);
    Activator.CreateInstance(myDynamicType);
}

public class GenericClass : GenericBase
{
}

public abstract class GenericBase
{
   private readonly List<IMyInterface> myList = new List<IMyInterface>();

   public void SomeMethod<T>() where T : IMyInterface, new ()
   {
       myList.Add(new T());
   }
}
```

Comment: can you tell us what you are doing in the SomeMethod?

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: See updated code.  I'm simply adding the object to a list which is used downstream.

Comment: @PMOrion are you wanting to instantiate `GenericClass` and call the `SomeMethod<T>` method on it from `MainClass`?

Comment: Correct, I need to instantiate GenericClass and call SomeMethod<T> from it's base class from the main method.  I'm dynamically getting the type (or class) from a configuration file that I need to pass to SomeMethod<T>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. The first involves modifying the `SomeMethod<T>` method to be non-generic or adding a non-generic overload:

```
public void SomeMethod(Type t) {
    var myInterface = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    myList.Add(myInterface);
}

public void SomeMethod<T>() where T : IMyInterface, new ()
{
   SomeMethod(typeof(T));
}
```

Then call is as follows:

```
var myDynamicType = Type.GetType(FullyQualifiedNamespace + className);  //I assume this is the type that you want to use as the generic constraint 'T' of SomeMethod<T>

var genericClass = new GenericClass();
genericClass.SomeMethod(myDynamicType);
```

Alternatively, you can leave the `SomeMethod<T>` method alone and invoke the method via reflection:

```
var myDynamicType = Type.GetType(FullyQualifiedNamespace + className);  //I assume this is the type that you want to use as the generic constraint 'T' of SomeMethod<T>

var genericClass = new GenericClass();
var method = typeof(GenericClass).GetMethod("SomeMethod").MakeGenericMethod(myDynamicType);
method.Invoke(genericClass);
```

Comment: I had started down the first path but unfortunately changing the signature wasn't an option.  But the latter way you provided is working.  I was missing that you could simply tell it to get the method from the base since it's in scope.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the method signature of `SomeMethod<T>()` with `SomeMethod(Type t)`.

```
public void SomeMethod(Type t)
    {
        if (t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyInterface)) && 
               t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)!=null)
        {
            var obj=(IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            myList.Add(obj);
        }
    }
```